# Replacing Path parts in Rust

Tags: replace, path, formatting, rust

Suppose I have the following three paths:

```
let file = path::Path::new("/home/meurer/test/a/01/foo.txt");
let src = path::Path::new("/home/meurer/test/a");
let dst = path::Path::new("/home/meurer/test/b");
```

Now, I want to copy `file` into `dst`, but for that I need to correct the paths, so that I can have `new_file` with a path that resolves to `/home/meurer/test/b/01/foo.txt`. In other words, how do I remove `src` from `file` and then append the result to `dst`?

`/home/meurer/test/a/01/foo.txt` -> `/home/meurer/test/b/01/foo.txt`

Note that we can't assume that `src` will always be this similar to `dst`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Path::strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.strip_prefix) and [`Path::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join):

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let file = Path::new("/home/meurer/test/a/01/foo.txt");
    let src = Path::new("/home/meurer/test/a");
    let dst = Path::new("/home/meurer/test/b");

    let relative = file.strip_prefix(src).expect("Not a prefix");
    let result = dst.join(relative);

    assert_eq!(result, Path::new("/home/meurer/test/b/01/foo.txt"));
}
```

As usual, you probably don't want to use `expect` in your production code, it's only for terseness of the answer.

Comment: Dang! too fast :P

Comment: @Centril Shepmaster always answer so fast, I just understand the question that Shepmaster answer ^^

Comment: @Centril In this case, I had an unfair advantage. The question was actually asked first in the [SO Rust chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) so I already had an answer prepared before the question was posted here ^_^.